# show options as another attribute of the same model form django

Tags: django, forms, model, entity-attribute-value, formset

I have the following models, because the intention is to have dynamic attributes for each item.

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
  label = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class Value(models.Model):
  attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute)
  value     = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class Item(models.Model):
  user          = models.ForeignKey(User, editable = False)
  title         = models.CharField(max_length = 150, blank = True)
  price         = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 8, decimal_places = 2, null = True)
  categories    = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class Datasheet(models.Model):
  item         = models.ForeignKey(Item, editable = False)
  attribute    = models.ForeignKey(Attribute)
  currentValue = models.ForeignKey(Value)
```

When I save no problem, but when I want to edit the value of the datasheet form shows me 
ALL POSSIBLE VALUES REGARDLESS OF ATTRIBUTE:

```
Datasheet 
Item: Mouse 
Attribute: Color 
Values: Red, Orange, Yellow, Blue, Apple, Honda, Yamaha
```

But I just need to see ATTRIBUTE VALUES FOR THAT.

```
Datasheet 
Item: Mouse 
Attribute: Color 
Values: Red, Orange, Yellow, Blue
```

In the view:

```
datasheetFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Item, Datasheet, form = DatasheetForm, extra = 0)
formsetDatasheet = datasheetFormSet(instance = item)
```

Anyone have experience with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved! =)

```
class DatasheetForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DatasheetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    id = self['attr'].value()
    self.fields['value'].queryset = Value.objects.filter(attr__pk = id)
  class Meta:
    model  = Datasheet
```